# How angles was calculated

Tags: soft-question

**In the past, how did they calculate the angles and sides of a right angle triangle without using a calculator?**

Comment: Protractors and rulers? The Pythagorean Theorem and trigonometry?

Comment: i don't know what they did in the past but i would use maclaurin's expansion.

Comment: What do you mean in the past? What does calculator mean? - before Sir Clive Sinclair's slim line pocket digital calculator, before analogue calculators or before mechanical calculators? Your question is so vague and ill defined. The answer could be via log tables and slide rules within my lifetime, right back to the manipulation of Egyptian fractions and other ancient systems of whole number and rational number mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: they didn’t.

To *calculate* something, you need a *calculator* or a *computer.*
Before electronic calculators there were mechanical calculators, and before that, computers were people with pencil and paper (or other means of recording the steps of their computations).

Seriously, “computer” used to be a job title under which numerous people were employed.

In the days when all computers were people, however, people rarely calculated trigonometric functions. Instead, most people who needed these results looked them up in books of trigonometric tables. It was far more efficient to have a relatively small number of computers work out all the data required to fill these tables and then to publish and distribute the books rather than have everyone who needed a sine or tangent have to calculate it themselves.

When two or three digits of accuracy was enough, devices such as slide rules could also be used. Again, this meant a relatively small number of people actually had to calculate where the marks on slide rules needed to be placed, and everyone else just used those markings to work with trigonometric functions.